# Passing props to React component tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a question about React, it's more of a theoretical kind.

So I have Root stateful component, which handles all the state manipulation and user interaction with callbacks. State and callbacks are passed as props down the tree, which consist of stateless functional components.

I've found myself passing the same props down the tree through multiple levels and it's really gotten out of hands now.

So what are my options? **I really don't want to add Flux/Redux**, it seems too complex IMHO. There is also React's context API, but its doc is full of scary warnings.

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: MobX is a nice alternative to Flux/Redux. It is what you make out of it, and there's barely any boilerplate. I migrated a whole project from tree-architecture to MobX. It was a bit of a pain, but afterwards it's so much more productive handling events crossing parallel components.

Answer (score 2):

Passing down props is the basic pattern of passing around state properties in react. If you have props you use in almost every component you could try [context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html).

But the point at which it gets complex to handle all the state via passing down props and context alone is usually the sign you want to use some tool which helps you to deal with managing state, i.e. Redux, MobX or one of the other tools out there.

Comment: So basically Flux is unavoidable? Sigh :(

Comment: @AntonMelnikov yes, I think so for deeply-nested/complex apps.

Comment: @AntonMelnikov I recently saw a list of Dan Abramov which contained the top feature requests of the React community and having the React state system work well for complex scenarios without the need of Redux or the-like was one of the top wishes.. So for now you should give some Flux implementation a try. Redux is most widely used but contains a lot of boilerplate code, so perhaps MobX is good for a start.. But you have to decide yourself.